# ngrx/store gives me Cannot find module './shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer" error

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

**I have installed only ngrx/store and then created reducer in shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer.ts**

```
import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';
import  * as ShoppingListActions from "./shopping-list.actions";


export const initialState = {
   
 ingredients: [
        new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
        new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 10),
    ]
};

export function shoppingListReducer(state = initialState, action: ShoppingListActions.AddIngredient){
   
switch (action.type) {
     
  case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
        
   return {
               ...state,
               ingredients: [
                   ...state.ingredients, action.payload
               ]
           };
   
   }
}
```

**and stored action at  shopping-list/store/shopping-list.action.ts.**

```
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";

import { Ingredient } from '../../shared/ingredient.model';


export const ADD_INGREDIENT = 'ADD_INGREDIENT'; 


export class AddIngredient implements Action{

   readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;

   payload: Ingredient; 
}
```

***but when i am trying to import this in app.module.ts file it shows me '
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:12:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer'.
12 import { shoppingListReducer } from './shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer';' this type of error***

**this is my app.module.ts file**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';



import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

import { CoreModule } from './core.module';


import { ErrorPageModule } from './error-page/error-page.module';

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store'; 

import { shoppingListReducer } from './shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer';


@NgModule({

  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent],

  imports: [

    BrowserModule,

    HttpClientModule,

    StoreModule.forRoot({ shoppingList: shoppingListReducer }),

    AppRoutingModule,

    SharedModule,

    CoreModule,

    ErrorPageModule,

  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  providers: []

})

export class AppModule {}
```

***Do i need to install anything extra  for that and "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0" has been installed.***

Comment: Maybe try: `import * as shoppingListReducer from './shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer';`

Comment: Resolved successfully. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the paths of the imports are correctly.

For example, try

```
import { shoppingListReducer } from '../shopping-list/store/shopping-list.reducer';
```

You can also remove the import and let the IDE figure it out.